# PostgreSQL adding two integer Arrays

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have two instances of the type `integer[]` (generated by the Timescale `histogram` function), e.g. `{3,5,1}` and `{2,2,2}`.
I would like to add these two Arrays to `{5,7,3}` but using

```sql
SELECT "ID", histogram(...) + histogram(...)
FROM "ID"
GROUP BY "ID"
```

throws the following error: `operator does not exist: integer[] + integer[]`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a function.

In order to achieve your goal (in SQL) you'd have to unnest the arrays, then add the corresponding elements and aggregate the results back to array.

```sql
SELECT 
  array_agg(
    COALESCE(h1.val, 0)+COALESCE(h2.val, 0) 
    ORDER BY COALESCE(h1.row_number, h2.row_number)
  ) as result
FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (), val FROM unnest('{3,5,1,5}'::int[]) as val) as h1
   FULL JOIN  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (), val FROM unnest('{2,2,2}'::int[]) as val) as h2 ON h1.row_number=h2.row_number
```

I'm using [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) window function to get the array element number.
FULL JOIN is required because the arrays may be of different length. It is also the reason why [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is required when adding the elements.

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name the query may be rewritten using ordinality without relying on row_number() function:

```sql
SELECT 
  array_agg(
    COALESCE(h1.val, 0)+COALESCE(h2.val, 0) 
    ORDER BY COALESCE(h1.no, h2.no)
  ) as result
FROM 
  unnest('{3,5,1,5}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY as h1(val, no)
  FULL JOIN unnest('{2,2,2}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY as h2(val, no) ON h1.no=h2.no
```

Comment: If you want to get the array element's index, use `from unnest(....) with ordinality as h1(val, idx)` no need to rely on row_number() for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to use this in a continuous aggregate which is a special materialized view for timescale, in these you can't use ORDER BY or subclauses, but its good to know that there probably is no such function